# Changing directory from current directory using lua script

Tags: lua

I want to know current working directory and then go back to parent directory of current directory using a Lua script.

For example:
Current directory: `C:\programs\lua_script`
Desired Output: `c:/programs/`

Comment: How to determine the current directory: `local pipe=io.popen"cd"; local dir=pipe:read"*a"; pipe:close(); print(dir)`

Comment: How to get the path of parent directory: `dir=dir:match("^.*\\")`

Answer (score 1):

Lua doesn't know or care what a directory is, and it can't change its current directory either.

You would need to use a platform-specific library for that, like luaposix on POSIX systems. As a workaround, you can query the current working directory by calling another program with `io.popen()` and parsing the output, but this won't allow you to change directory.